# Use favicon *.ico in css background

Tags: css, html, google-chrome-extension

I am building a chrome extension that uses a searchable listbox to conduct common commands. The windows open tabs will also appear in this listbox, and the `Tab` object comes with a favIconUrl that will sometimes contain *.png, or *.ico references, etc.

I would like to style my list items with the *.ico, but it looks like css is not going to respect icons. I was thinking there might be a service that would dynamically convert the icon to a png or something useful with css.

Then I could use `background-image: url(http://ico2png.com/convert?ico=<favIconUrl>);`

Is there any such animal out there, or an alternative method?

EDIT:

My bad, it looks like this does work, in Chrome.

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/favicon.ico">
<div style="height:32px;width:32px;background-image:url(https://www.google.com/favicon.ico);">

</div>
```

I thought it might be that the ico was really a png, but I guess not. I will leave the question open for other browsers, since I do not have the time to investigate.

Comment: None that I know of, but you could build one easily with anything that can execute imagemagick or similar.

Comment: also use google's favicon fetching service for more relyability:
http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain_url=my_url

Comment: ICO images work in all browsers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can not recommend using direct favicon urls in your code.
Many websites have the favicon not in their root directory.

But no worry you have plenty of alternatives.

### 1. Chrome Favicons

You can use the chrome favicons. These will be served by the browser cache.

#### manifest.json

```
"permissions": [
    ...
    "chrome://favicon/"
]
```

#### background.js

If you want to use the icons in a page context (contentscripts) you might have to convert them to a dataURL in order to bypass the CORS restrictions.

```
function convertImgToBase64URL(url, callback, outputFormat){
    var img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'), dataURL;
        canvas.height = img.height;
        canvas.width = img.width;
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        dataURL = canvas.toDataURL(outputFormat);
        callback(dataURL);
        canvas = null; 
    };
    img.src = url;
}

function getFaviconFromURL(url, callback){
  return convertImgToBase64URL("chrome://favicon/" + url, callback);
}

getFaviconFromURL('http://google.com', function(dataURL){
  console.log(dataURL);
});
```

You can even get different icons sizes:

```
chrome://favicon/size/16@1x/https://www.google.com
chrome://favicon/size/16@2x/https://www.google.com
```

### 2. Use a Favicon API

- http://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=

Comment: It is a good answer, the only problem is knowing which URL cached the favicon, since providing the wrong URL will return the default icon. This is difficult to determine.

See: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/20f8aa123f98b2bcb0d346af0d78ad7a8ddea5d0/chrome/browser/sync/glue/favicon_cache.h#79

and: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/20f8aa123f98b2bcb0d346af0d78ad7a8ddea5d0/chrome/browser/sync/glue/favicon_cache.h#86